# Ignore Jenkins job if commit message starts with a given string

Tags: git, jenkins

I want to ignore running a Jenkins job if the commit message starts with a given string. I've tried adding "Additional Behaviours" and "Polling ignores commits with certain messages":

[image]

I.e. I want to ignore the job (which in my world means don't run the job) if the commit message starts with "doc!". I've tried several online regex matchers and I think that the regex of `^doc!.*` is correct. But even though my commit messages does start with "doc!" the job is executed by Jenkins. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While @devanshu-dwivedi's answer might work my approach seem to work as well if I change my regex to:

`(?s)^doc!.*`

I don't exactly know why this is the case. The documentation says that using `(?s)` checks multiple comment lines in the commit messages. But without using `(?s)` it don't work for me even for single commits with a one line commit message.

Comment: @Devanshu Dwivedi: I want to skip Jenkins build when a commit message with ci skip text.. I wrote below code to do this.. need inputs on this or any better solution..                                                                                      

`builders:`
   ` - conditional-step:`
        `condition-kind: regex-match`
`        regex: .*ci\W+skip.*`
`        label: $GIT_COMMIT`
 `       on-evaluation-failure: run`

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins Git plugin exposes you the environment variable GIT_COMMIT which of course, contains the current git commit hash. Use [Jenkins Conditional Step] and build a step which execute the following bash shell:

```
echo "==========================="

if [ "git show $GIT_COMMIT | grep ".doc" == false  ] ; then
    echo "pattern failed";
    exit 1
else
    echo "ok"
fi

echo "==========================="
```

And mark that if the shell fails, fail the build.

Comment: This is failing the build if the commit contains the matching phrase. The question was to ignore it (in fact specifically it said "don't run the job"). It certainly shouldn't be putting the branch in to an error state if it wasn't in one before. It's also an unnecessary shell script for something easily checked in a pipeline script itself (which can access that using `env.GIT_COMMIT`).