# Continuous integration creates a build loop

Tags: jenkins, github, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I have a `Webhook` for my repository in github which is triggered when there is a push to master branch and then webhook starts the build in `Jenkins`

At the end of build process, I change the version in the pom and push it to master again which would trigger the webhook again and make a loop of builds in Jenkins.

Is there something I can do about this? What is the better practice for this scenario?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you deliver a new change you can commit with a specific message like ('pom  modified from jenkins build'). Then add a rule in Jenkins Git plugin to ignore commits with that message ("Polling ignores commit with certain messages" using exact or a pattern). This way you avoid an infinite loop!

Comment: So I have a commit message like `"Release new version $NEW_VERSION"`, but even if I set the excluded pattern to `.*` which is every character the build still triggers.

Comment: if anyone has this problem, you could find the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36398867/ignore-jenkins-job-if-commit-message-starts-with-a-given-string

Answer (score 0):

Try and break the loop by pushing the updated pom to a dedicated "`release`" branch from which the final release is built (and the webhook you mention is *not* active)

From there, any new development should first merge the latest release (and get the updated pom), before making new commits for the next feature to merge to `master`.